# How can I use the up/down history keys in the SWI-Prolog console?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, swi-prolog

When I press up/down, I should get - just like unix - the previous commands, but instead I get:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 32 bits, Version 6.0.0)
Copyright (c) 1990-2011 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

1 ?- ['nc'].
% nc compiled into nc 0.00 sec, 84 clauses
true.

2 ?- listing.
true.
```

(I press 'Up' arrow key to get the 'listing' command back.. then..)

```
3 ?- **^[[A**
```

I compiled from source without any additional 'configure', or 'make' parameters.

In previous version of swi-prolog, I found this worked haphazardly.. sometimes the console got itself in a mess, and I had to press '.' to force it to terminate the current line, then the history would start working again.

But this latest version.. nada..  I am using ubuntu linux, bash shell. It feels like an o.s. environment issue, or a bug in swi-prolog. The arrow keys/history works fine at the linux level.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about swi-prolog in particular, but I have used [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) to solve this problem for other interpreters that didn't feature built in editing features. It's very simple to use; you just have rlwrap run the command instead of running it directly.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Since Ubuntu did it's usual update, my problem has disappeared. But if it comes back, I'll try this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install package `libreadline-dev` on your host before compiling swiprolog to have arrows working.

Comment: This works, and should be flagged as the solution so far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually an answer, more of a workaround, just in case anyone else has the same problem.

Although the 'up/down' arrow keys appear broken in 6.0.0 (and .1 - just tried it), the 'command-based' history recall seems to work ok, so it's possible to retrieve previous commands that way.

eg.

```
3 ?- !!.
listing.
true.

4 ?- L='fred', integer(L).
false.

5 ?- !!. 
L='fred', integer(L).
false.

6 ?- h.
    1   listing.
    2   listing.
    3   listing.
    4   L='fred', integer(L).
    5   L='fred', integer(L).
6 ?- !3.
listing.
true.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in OSX, and I fixed it this way:

```
brew install rlwrap

# every time when launching swipl:
rlwrap swipl
```